# Does Visual Studio 2010 have SQL syntax highlighting for .sql files?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-addins

Basically the title is my question.

I have a project in one of my solutions just for storing development assets like DB creation scripts and the like. While I normally use SSMS for developing and running these scripts, I would like to be able to open them in Visual Studio and see the same syntax highlighting that's in SSMS.

It's just a superficial thing, but would be nice. Anyone know?

If not, anyone know of any addons that can do this?

Comment: Its built in, it may be a specific version and up, which VS 2010 flavor are you using?

Comment: I will be using Professional edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

And, this one word answer was too short.  So I'm addding this nonsense. Feel free to ignore it.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this varies version to version?